# Efficient way to outer multiply two large 1D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply two arrays, with each possible combination of elements. For instance

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [1, 2, 3]
# Result -> [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9]
```

My arrays are of length 10000. I've tried this approach:

```
np.multiply.outer(data, data2)
```

However, I get this error:

```
\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)
    724 
    725         inputs = tuple(extract_array(x, extract_numpy=True) for x in inputs)
--> 726         result = getattr(ufunc, method)(*inputs, **kwargs)
    727 
    728         name = names[0] if len(set(names)) == 1 else None

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 74.5 GiB for an array with shape (100000, 100000) and data type float64
```

Any way to do it?

Comment: Yes, `np.multply.outer` is what you want. Maybe you need to find a computer with more than `74.5 GB` of RAM :-). Or you would need to save your data to disc not memory.

Comment: how can I force to do it in memory instead?

Comment: `outer` works fine with those two example arrays, doesn't it, producing a (3,3) result.  The problem isn't with `multiply.outer`, it's with the size of the arrays.  Do you really need to form the outer product of arrays that big?  100000*100000*8=80G

Answer (score 0):

Are your matrices sparse? meaning a lot of cells have value = 0?
If so, you could use scipy's sparse matrix. This module very efficiently deals with large arrays.
I believe this example suits what you are asking for:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.kron.html#scipy.sparse.kron

Comment: I have two suggestions:
- It seems like this type of multiplication can be done by chunks? how about multiplying one row or a subset of A at a time? similar to https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/477500-how-can-i-multiply-two-big-matrices-avoiding-out-of-memory 
- What is the max value in the arrays? You could for instance change your array dtype to np.uint8 which will save you a lot of memory, but be cautious because this dtype does not allow any value bigger than 2^8. (2^16, 2^32 and 2^64 also available) https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html

Comment: the values are float64, I've tried uint8 however, the values round to 0. Is there a solution with float?

Comment: You can try `numpy.half / numpy.float16`

Comment: Changing dtype just postpones the memory error.  It is hard to enforce those smaller dtypes across all calculations, and hard to limit the number of temporary buffers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a chunked solution that should dump to disk in the correct order:

```
a = np.arange(10000)
b = a[::-1]   # 'cause why not

chunk_size = 500
with open('output.dat', 'w') as f:
    for c in a.split(np.arange(chunk_size, a.size + 1, chunk_size)):
        np.tofile(np.multiply.outer(c, b))
```

Each `c` should be a view into `a`, so the only new data you are creating is with `np.multiply.outer(c, b)`. You can control the size of the intermediate output by modifying `chunk_size` to ensure that the operation fits into memory. The binary data in `output.dat` will be the output you want, stored in row-major (C) order.